# Multi threaded program hangs on condition wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have the following piece of code. I am using c++11 threads to write a simple multi threaded producer consumer problem.

```
class W
{
public:
    explicit W();
    void p();
    void c();
private:
    std::deque<std::uint64_t> q;
    std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> m;
    std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable> cvQEmpty;
    std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable> cvQFull;
    const std::size_t queue_size;
};

W::W()
: m(std::make_shared<std::mutex>()), 
cvQEmpty(std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>()),
cvQFull(std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>()),
queue_size(3)  
{
}

void
W::p()
{
    while(1)    
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*m.get());
        if (q.size() >= queue_size)
        {
            cvQFull->wait(lk, [this] { return q.size() < queue_size; });
        }
        q.push_back(q.size());
        std::cout << "Pushed " << q[q.size() - 1] << std::endl;
        lk.unlock();
        cvQEmpty->notify_one();
    }
}

void
W::c()
{
  while (1)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*m.get());
    if (q.empty())
    {
        cvQEmpty->wait(lk, [this] { return !q.empty(); });
    }
    while(!q.empty())
    {
      const std::uint64_t val = q[0];
      std::cout << "Output : " << val << std::endl;
      q.pop_back();
    }
    lk.unlock();
    cvQFull->notify_one();
  }
}

void 
foo()
{
    W w;
    std::thread p(&W::p, w);
    std::thread c(&W::c, w);
    c.join();
    p.join();
}
```

Both the threads are deadlocked on condition wait.

Could you please tell me where I am going wrong. The program compiles fine without any warnings.

Compiler Used is : g++-5.8

Comment: Do you have any log? like Pushed 1, Pushed 2.. Did it hang when the queue is Full? because producer locks the mutex and waits for queue size to decrease, but consumer will wait to get hold of the mutex locked by producer in order to consume.. hence deadlocked..

Comment: You don't need any shared_ptrs, there's nothing to share. Use plain `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple. You are **copying** your `w` argument to both threads, invoking copy constructor. Those threads end up using two indepenent queues!

Solutions:

- Make your queue a `shared_ptr` like mutex
- (better) encompass your argument into `std::ref`.

(On a side note, `explicit W()` gives you nothing and is just syntax noise)